# Quantas linhas uma função "inline" deve ter? em quais casos o "inline" será desconsiderado?

Tags: c, c++, funções, inline

o C++ possuí uma palavra-chave chamada "inline" que serve para alterar a forma em como o compilador realizará a chamada de uma função. Estou ciente que é recomendado que o tamanho dessa função seja pequena, mas, não tenho ideia de quantas linhas máximas uma função inline deveria ter. Além disso, vi em algum lugar na internet que quando o corpo de uma função inline tiver algum loop (while, for, do-while...), ela deixaria de ser considerada inline. Não sei se essa informação é verdadeira e, caso seja, também gostaria de saber em quais casos uma função inline é desconsiderada. Alguém poderia me ajudar nessas perguntas?

1. Quantas linhas máximas uma função inline deve ter?
2. Em quais casos uma função deixa de ser inline?

Answer (score -2):

Não existe nenhum limite para o número de linhas. Existem as seguintes restrições:

- Não pode ter ciclos
- Não pode ter switch ou goto.
- A função não pode ser recursiva.
- O retorno tem que ser void.
- Não pode ter variáveis static.